# Combining two dataframes to calculate variable when column names are equal to row values

Tags: r

I have two dataframes: one dataframe that has dichotomous variables representing whether a string match is present, and a second dataframe that applies "weights" for that string across different dimensions.

For example, `df1` might look like this:

```
organic    gluten_free    kosher   sugar_free
1          0              0        0
1          1              0        1
1          1              0        1
0          0              1        0
1          0              1        0
```

The **row values** in the second dataframe (`df2`) should match the values of the *column names* in `df1`, and with the value in each row representing a weight.

```
attribute    eco-friendly     healthy 
organic      2                3         
gluten_free  1                4         
kosher       3                3         
sugar_free   2                3
```

I then want to calculate the product of the weight for each row value in `df1` when the `colname` in `df1` is equal to the row value in `df2` into separate indices. For clarity, I have included the specific calculations for the `eco-friendly` index below:

```
organic    gluten_free    kosher   sugar-free  eco-friendly
1          0              0        0           (1*2 + 0*1 + 0*3 + 0*2)
1          1              0        1           (1*2 + 1*1 + 0*3 + 1*2)
1          1              0        1           (1*2 + 1*1 + 0*3 + 1*2)
0          0              1        0           (0*2 + 0*1 + 1*3 + 0*2)
1          0              1        0           (1*2 + 0*1 + 1*3 + 0*2)
```

I have written a very ugly and slow loop function to complete this task, but am confident a more elegant solution exists. Some additional sample data is below.

```
> dput(df1[1:100,]) 
structure(list(organic = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0"), gluten_free = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0",  "1", "0"), kosher = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1",  "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",  "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0",  "1")), row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",  "10", "11", "12", "15", "17", "18", "19", "22", "23", "24", "25",  "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36",  "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47",  "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58",  "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69",  "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "83",  "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "91", "92", "93", "95", "97", "98",  "101", "103", "105", "106", "108", "117", "124", "125", "127",  "129", "131", "132", "133", "136", "137"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(df2[1:3,]) 
structure(list(attribute = c("organic", "gluten_free", "kosher"), eco_friendly = c(1L, 3L, 2L), healthy = c(2L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = 1:3, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take the dot product of the two `df`s, keeping in mind that the `%*%` operator only works for numeric matrices:

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.numeric)
output <- cbind(df1, as.matrix(df1) %*% as.matrix(df2[,-1]))
```

The downside to this is that the columns in `df1` and the rows in `df2` have to be in the correct order. To make sure the column and row order matches, we can use the following in place of `df2[,-1]`:

`df2[match(names(df1), df2$attribute),-1]`

**Output:**

```
> head(output)
  organic gluten_free kosher eco_friendly healthy
2       0           0      0            0       0
3       0           1      0            3       0
4       0           0      0            0       0
5       0           0      0            0       0
6       0           1      0            3       0
7       0           0      0            0       0
```

Comment: So to avoid the likelihood of an error, would it make sense to add something like: `df1<-df1[ , order(names(df1))]` and `df2 <- df2[order(df2$attribute),]` to ensure that the code works correctly?

Comment: @roody Yes, that would be a safe way to do it.

Comment: Another q about a related extension: is there an efficient way to normalize the indexed scores in `df1` to the maximum possible sum of weights for the columns in `df2` within this function? My initial idea is to divide by `colSums(pr[,-1])` but want to make sure that's right.

Comment: @roody or you can do `df2[match(names(df1), df2$attribute),]`

Comment: @roody You will have to elaborate on that by showing what you mean with an example. For example, you will have to explain what you mean by "normalize" and "maximum possible sum of weights"

Comment: In this solution, each row in `df1` will have index score(s) that are the product of a dichotomous variable and a weight. Theoretically, there could be rows that have matches (=1) for all attributes in `df2`, which would make the maximum possible index score the sum of all weights in that column (e.g. `sum(df2$eco_friendly))`. By "normalize," I mean construct a measure capturing the relative score to the max value for that index, rather than the sum. Aware this includes a lot of assumptions about linearity/what an increment of "1" truly means - just curious about execution.

Comment: @roody I see, so do you mean adding two columns in the final output, one for `eco-friendly` and one for `healthy`, where you divide each row of `eco-friendly` by `sum(df2$eco-friendly)` and each row of `healthy` by `sum(df2$healthy)`? In this case, your idea should work: `output <- cbind(df1, (as.matrix(df1) %*% as.matrix(df2[,-1]))/colSums(df2[,-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df <- data.frame(organic = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1), gluten_free = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),           
                 kosher = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), sugar_free = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0))
df %>% mutate(eco_friendly = organic * 2 + gluten_free * 1 + kosher * 3 + sugar_free * 2)
```

Comment: Isn't this just hard-coding the formula OP gave? I would think they wanted a dynamic solution without spelling out each position of the index

Comment: Okay, got it. Shouldn't be that obviuos :O